# Strong maximum principle for weak solutions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Suppose I have a linear parabolic equation with solutions in the Bochner-Sobolev spaces (eg. $L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap H^1(0,T;H^{-1})$). Is it possible to obtain a strong maximum principle with a proof that does not rely on classical solutions or techniques (and with minimal semigroup theory as possible)?

By the strong maximum principle I mean that:

> if the parabolic operator has some given sign and the maximum occurs in the interior then the solution must be a constant.

I read the thread [Maximum principle for weak solutions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61044/maximum-principle-for-weak-solutions) but it is slightly different. Note I also posted this on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910740/strong-maximum-principle-for-weak-solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not immediately sure how to formulate a *strong* maximum principle if you are trying to avoid "classical" techniques where you understand the solution as being regular enough to be well-defined pointwise.  I'm also a little unclear as to which techniques you do or don't want to use.

However, I will mention that Grigor'yan and Hu obtained a maximum principle for weak solutions in the context of a metric measure space equipped with a symmetric Dirichlet form, which may include examples of interest or suggest a useful approach.  See Section 4 of:

> Grigorʹyan, Alexander; Hu, Jiaxin. 
>   Off-diagonal upper estimates for the heat kernel of the Dirichlet forms on metric spaces. 
>   *Invent. Math.* **174** (2008), no. 1, 81–126. [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2430977) [Article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00222-008-0135-9)

Laurent Saloff-Coste and I recorded a slightly different version (and included a few other details in the proof) in our paper "Widder's theorem for symmetric local Dirichlet spaces", which is [on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1926) and will appear in *Journal of Theoretical Probability*.

Comment: Thanks for the references, will check them. Regarding your first sentence, an a.e. strong maximum principle will do.